# Free Web Based Server Log Viewer/Monitor

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, monitoring, logging

I'm not much of a server guy, but do need to monitor logs for my web server. Preferabbly, PHP, Apache and MySQL error logs. Could you guys offer any advice for free web-based solutions for monitoring these server logs?

It's a linux server.

Comment: Shopping Questions are considered Off-Topic here on ServerFault.  Please see the [Help](http://serverfault.com/help) section or [Here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more info.  **If you are interested in having a way to ask these types of questions** head over to the [IT Shopping Questions Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59278/it-shopping-questions) and post your question as a possible question for the beta and follow the proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)** is excellent and free if you are generating under 500Mb of logs per day

Answer (score 2):

Well, im currently using [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)

There is not much that you cannot do with the software and it is all free! There are plugins for monitoring all kinds of logs. Its a bit of a pain to setup but fantastic once its all working. If you cannot find a plugin, you can write your own quite easily.

Ive also just setup [Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), which is fantastic for monitoring IIS logs, the website says it supports Apache logs, not tested though

Answer (score 1):

A good solution maybe [Graylog2](http://graylog2.org/), but only for one Server this might be a bit overdosed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [Octopussy](https://www.octopussy.pm) (disclaimer: my project).

You can do a lot of things with it (search, store, alerts, reports) and it's totally free (no limits to 500Mb/day) !

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends what you want to see from your logs.

For marketing oriented web metrics, you'd have to go a long way to find something better than Google Analytics - which is free for low volumes. [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) and [OWA](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/) intended to provide similar functionality.

For a more basic facility there's [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), webalizer and more.

See also [this page](http://bloggingwithoutablog.com/how-to-capitalize-on-your-blog-statistics/).

However there's very little (nothing?) available for detailled performance analysis. I use a compbination of some home grown scripts along with [this script for de-parameterizing](http://www.retards.org/projects/mysql/) mysql query logs.

When I've got some time to kill I intend looking at building something out of [Yahoo Boomerang](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/06/performance_testing_with_boomerang/) and [Graphite](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/).

Answer (score 0):

As symcbean says, it depends what you want. If you're using logs as a way to measure traffic, I'd second his suggestion of using Google Analytics. For realtime traffic, try GA's new [Realtime](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/09/whats-happening-on-your-site-right-now.html) feature or [Gaug.es](http://gaug.es).

If you want raw log visibility, like for searching/tail the logs and triggering alerts from the contents, my service [Papertrail](http://papertrailapp.com/) has a free account. You get a remote syslog target and paste that into syslog.conf (or [remote_syslog](https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog)).

I'd suggest trying a couple things to see what you really use. More features is not always better (and when they aren't features you really want, they'll often get in the way. There's no substitute for a couple weeks of using something yourself.